# Class not found when initialising it inside another class construct

Tags: php, oop

I'm still getting my head around some OOP bits. I have a main class engine.php

Its job is basically to act as an API type, to access the functions of the other classes.

```
class Engine
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->likes = new Rater('likes');
        $this->dislikes = new Rater('dislikes');
        $this->similars = new Similars();

    }
}
```

When I try and use it though by loading the class in the construct of another it comes up with an error.

```
class Similars
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->engine = new Engine();
    }
}

$userLikes = $this->engine->likes->items_by_user();
```

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Engine' not found in
>   recommendation-engine\class.vgurec-similars.php:14.

It could be my OOP begginer-ness but I am not sure what is causing the problem. I've had a look at namespaces and autoloading but not sure which is the right route to take.

Comment: This might sound snide, but are you sure the file is being included from a scope where you can access it from the class you're using? Short of that, check your namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi include the flie by

```
include 'filename.php';
```

Comment: Silly me completely forgot to include the class...such a rookie mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For making an object a class, you must need to include that class first. Without it, you will get this types of error. Be confirm that, the class file is included.